# Как при вызове функции (без аргумента) выводить следующее число Фибоначчи?

Tags: javascript, функции, frontend

Как реализовать через функцию последовательность Фибоначчи в JavaScript, таким образом, чтобы последующее число выводилось при каждом вызове функции, не передавая аргумент?

С аргументом я сделал. Но нужно именно при каждом вызове.

Буду признателен за подробное объяснение.

Вот реализация с аргументом:

```
 function helperFibonacci (n) {
 let number1 = 0;
 let number2 = 1;

 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
 let current = number1 + number2;
 number1 = number2;
 number2 = current;
     console.log(current);
  }
 }

 helperFibonacci(2);
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Не совсем ясно. Можете прикрепить то, что есть и как-то объяснить на примере что нужно

Comment: Нужно сделать функцию, которая будет выводить последующее число Фибоначчи при каждом ее вызове.

Comment: Я разве не понятно выразился что нужно?((

Comment: Ок. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: вот такие нужно делать заголовки, чтобы сразу было понятно, в чем задача. А не писать туда абы что

Comment: Спасибо! Буду учиться!)

Comment: @АртемН через замыкание

Comment: Можно использовать функции генераторы. Набросал [небольшой пример](https://jsfiddle.net/Denisdude/2Lh5b41g/). Подробное объяснение искать по запросу `функции генераторы js`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать замыкание. Создадим функцию, которая принимает на вход числа и замыкает их, возвращая функцию вычисления числа Фибоначчи. Здесь для читаемости можно разделить функцию на две: одну для генерации функции вычисления, вторую как саму функцию для вызова. Я же использовал IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) - сразу вызываемое выражение функции

```
const getFibonacci = ((prev = 0, next = 1) => () => {
    const result = prev + next
    prev = next
    next = result
    return result
  })()

getFibonacci() // 1
getFibonacci() // 2
getFibonacci() // 3
getFibonacci() // 5
getFibonacci() // 8
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let num1 = 0;
let num2 = 1;

function helperFibonacci () {
    let a = num1;
    let b = num2;
    let c = num1;
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = num2 + c;
    return a+b;
}

helperFibonacci();
```

Answer (score -1):

Самая быстрая из найденных мной когда-либо реализаций:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52877762/14255891

```js
const fibonacci = (n, a = 0, b = 1) => n === 0 ? a : fibonacci(n - 1, b, a + b);
const fibonacciBigInt = (n, a = 0n, b = 1n) => n === 0n ? a : fibonacciBigInt(n - 1n, b, a + b);

console.log(fibonacci(25));
console.log(fibonacciBigInt(250n).toString());

const fibGen = ()=>{
  let num = 0n;
  const getNext = ()=>fibonacciBigInt(++num).toString();
  return getNext;
};
let fib = fibGen();

for(let i = 0; i < 249; i++) fib();
console.log(fib());
console.log(fib());
console.log(fib());
for(let i = 0; i < 747; i++) fib();
console.log(fib().split(/(\d{1,60})/g).filter(Boolean).join(' '));
for(let i = 0; i < 3999; i++) fib();
console.log(fib().split(/(\d{1,60})/g).filter(Boolean).join(' '));
```